# How to set ProgID for file extension in ClickOnce deployment

Tags: uwp, manifest, clickonce

I am attempting to register a protocol handler with a specified ProgID

```
 <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <uap:Protocol Name="callto" >
          <rescap3:MigrationProgIds>
              <rescap3:MigrationProgId>Foo.Uri.1</rescap3:MigrationProgId>
          </rescap3:MigrationProgIds>
      </uap:Protocol >
 </uap:Extension>
```

However, I get a warning in my .appxmanifest of invalid child element on MigrationProgIds although the package builds and installs. Instead of the expected entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT of Foo.Uri.1 I get something along the lines of ProgId="AppXnhz4zkbe9t8kpaax3epmedatp0f4kh8e"

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of MigrationProgId or is there something wrong with my markup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation:[rescap3:MigrationProgIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-rescap3-migrationprogids), the `rescap3:MigrationProgIds` node should be the child of `uap:FileTypeAssociation` not the `uap:Protocol`.

The Hierarchy should be like this:

```
<Package>
<Applications>
<Application>
<Extensions>
<uap:Extension>
<uap:FileTypeAssociation>
<rescap3:MigrationProgIds>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at this. Even with a FileTypeAssociation it doesn't seem to work.

```
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
              <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="anyfile">
                  <rescap3:MigrationProgIds>
                      <rescap3:MigrationProgId>Foo.Uri.1</rescap3:MigrationProgId>
                  </rescap3:MigrationProgIds>
                  <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
                      <uap:FileType>.xyzaa</uap:FileType>
                      
                  </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
          </uap:Extension>
```

Gives

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Extensions\windows.fileTypeAssociation\.xyzaa\AppXnj0tkrmetettm359b15sxd27dgfxkbb6]
```

Again the Appxxx rather than the progid of Foo.Uri.1

I'm wondering if I'm trying to bend clickonce into doing something it isn't designed to do.

Comment: Is your app a desktop application or a UWP application? I've found an example that uses this-[Github-desktop-to-uwp-extension](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/blob/docs/hub/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions.md). It seems that this should work for desktop application.